# Few newbie react-native questions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and react-native (and pretty much everything in general...), I'm trying to follow [facebook's tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html) on state and props. I'm playing around with the code and I ran into some issues.

I've modified my `Apps.js` to look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f1f',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

class Blink extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {showText: true};

    // Toggle the state every second
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(previousState => {
        return { showText: !previousState.showText };
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    let display = this.state.showText ? this.props.text1 : this.props.text2;
    let pic = this.state.showText ? {uri: this.props.url1} : {uri: this.props.url2}
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={pic} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
        <Text>{display}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class BlinkApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Blink text1='test1' />
        <Blink text2='test2' />
        <Blink url1='https://www.gizbot.com/img/2015/08/10-1439192289-lolemoji.jpg' />
        <Blink url2='http://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/haha-nelson-simpsons.jpg' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Instead of blinking three lines of text like the one in the tutorial, it's suppose to blink two different images with two different lines of text (`text1` and `text2`) using my own `StyleSheet`. The issue I'm running into is that they are not properly aligned. I can't get them to center no matter what I try.

The two different images it displays/blinks are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7R7S.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stAk5.jpg)

What I want them to look like are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8aLC.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewLIS.jpg)

So my questions are:

1) Does it matter where I define `style`? e.g. in my code, I've included them inside the second `render`, but I've noticed that if I put them inside the first `render`, different results occur. What is the difference?

2) Am I using `props` incorrectly here? What should I be doing instead to define the two images and texts as part of my `props`?

3) Are `setInterval` and `previousState` native react libraries? How are they being called? i.e. what's triggering `setInterval` to change the value of `showText`?

4) when is `setState` being called?

Comment: your code is completely incorrect, I think you should learn React syntax first.

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope. This is a question and answer site; note that *question* is singular. It's not a *here's my numbered list of questions*. If you have multiple questions, create separate posts for each one; you can link back to this one for reference if needed. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your code, and I think it works as your expect now.

to your questions:

1&2: the way you use `style` and `props` is wrong, see my code below.

3: `setInterval` is native react libraries, you can find the usage in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.html

4: `setState` is called by your code, please look at the document https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#f1f',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

class Blink extends Component {
  render() {
    const { text, url } = this.props;
    console.log('url' + url);
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={{uri:url, cache: 'force-cache'}} style={{width: 193, height: 110}}/>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class BlinkApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      showFirst: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        showFirst: !this.state.showFirst
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const showFirst = this.state.showFirst;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {showFirst && <Blink url="https://www.gizbot.com/img/2015/08/10-1439192289-lolemoji.jpg" text='test1' />}
        {!showFirst && <Blink url="http://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/haha-nelson-simpsons.jpg" text='test2' />}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```